# Optimising a query of an SSRS dataset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, optimization

Consider the query given below:

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT          c.cust_id ,
                c.username ,
                REPLACE(qs.seg_type_ref_key_02, 'N/A', 'Non Vip') casino_group,
                REPLACE(qs.seg_type_ref_key_03, 'N/A', 'Non Vip') bingo_group,
                REPLACE(qs.seg_type_ref_key_04, 'N/A', 'Non Vip') games_group,
                REPLACE(qs.seg_type_ref_key_12, 'N/A', 'Non Vip') poker_group,
                REPLACE(qs.seg_type_ref_key_01, 'N/A', 'Non ViP') sportsbook_group,
                c.country
                , c.contactable
                , c.email
                , c.dob
                , c.[status]
                , c.first_name
                , c.last_name
                , c.[master]
                , c.[language]
                , c.gender
FROM  warehouse.dbo.dim_customer c (nolock)

INNER JOIN warehouse . dbo . dim_segmentationcodehistory ( nolock )sc
 ON sc . cust_id = c . cust_id
INNER JOIN warehouse . dbo . q_dim_segments qs ( nolock )
 ON sc . seg_code_ref_key = qs . seg_code_ref_key
WHERE SC.active=1 and qs.seg_type_ref_key_04 <>'N/A' AND c.active = 1
and (qs.seg_type_ref_key_02 <> 'Prospect' and qs.seg_type_ref_key_03 <> 'Prospect' and qs.seg_type_ref_key_04 <> 'Prospect' and qs.seg_type_ref_key_12 <> 'Prospect' and qs.seg_type_ref_key_01 <> 'Prospect')) A
LEFT JOIN( SELECT   c.cust_id cust_dup,
                    SUM(fc.turnover) AS Turnover_GBP,
                    SUM(fc.grosswin) AS GrossWin_GBP,
                    SUM(fc.chip_purch_amount_gbp) AS chip_purch_amount_gbp
FROM   warehouse.dbo.fact_games fc (nolock)
INNER JOIN warehouse.dbo.dim_date d (nolock)
 ON d.date_key = fc.date_ref_key
INNER JOIN warehouse.dbo.dim_customer c (nolock)
 ON c.cust_ref_key = fc.cust_ref_key
INNER JOIN warehouse.dbo.dim_gamesgame gg(nolock)
 ON gg.games_game_ref_key = fc.game_ref_key
WHERE d.[date] between getdate()- 10 AND getdate()-9
            AND gg.Game_Group_Description <> 'Bingo'
GROUP BY c.cust_id )B
ON A.cust_id = B.cust_dup)
```

This query takes a little more than an  hour. However, I require that this completes in as little time as possible.

Below is the level to which I have been able to optimize it:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_shash_A') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp_shash_A

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_shash_B') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp_shash_B

-- A
(SELECT          c.cust_id ,
            c.username ,
            REPLACE(qs.seg_type_ref_key_02, 'N/A', 'Non Vip')     casino_group,
            REPLACE(qs.seg_type_ref_key_03, 'N/A', 'Non Vip')     bingo_group,
            REPLACE(qs.seg_type_ref_key_04, 'N/A', 'Non Vip')     games_group,
            REPLACE(qs.seg_type_ref_key_12, 'N/A', 'Non Vip') poker_group,
            REPLACE(qs.seg_type_ref_key_01, 'N/A', 'Non ViP') sportsbook_group,
            c.country
            , c.contactable
            , c.email
            , c.dob
            , c.[status]
            , c.first_name
            , c.last_name
            , c.[master]
            , c.[language]
            , c.gender
INTO #temp_shash_A              
FROM  warehouse.dbo.dim_customer c (nolock)

INNER JOIN warehouse . dbo . dim_segmentationcodehistory ( nolock )sc
ON sc . cust_id = c . cust_id
INNER JOIN warehouse . dbo . q_dim_segments qs ( nolock )
ON sc . seg_code_ref_key = qs . seg_code_ref_key
WHERE SC.active=1 and qs.seg_type_ref_key_04 <>'N/A'  AND c.active = 1
and (qs.seg_type_ref_key_02 <> 'Prospect' and qs.seg_type_ref_key_03 <> 'Prospect' and      qs.seg_type_ref_key_04 <> 'Prospect' and qs.seg_type_ref_key_12 <> 'Prospect' and      qs.seg_type_ref_key_01 <> 'Prospect')
)

create clustered index S_1 on #temp_shash_A (cust_id)

-- B

( SELECT   c.cust_id cust_dup,
                SUM(fc.turnover) AS Turnover_GBP,
                SUM(fc.grosswin) AS GrossWin_GBP,
                SUM(fc.chip_purch_amount_gbp) AS chip_purch_amount_gbp
INTO #temp_shash_B
FROM   warehouse.dbo.fact_games fc (nolock)
INNER JOIN warehouse.dbo.dim_date d (nolock)
ON d.date_key = fc.date_ref_key
INNER JOIN warehouse.dbo.dim_customer c (nolock)
ON c.cust_ref_key = fc.cust_ref_key
INNER JOIN warehouse.dbo.dim_gamesgame gg(nolock)
ON gg.games_game_ref_key = fc.game_ref_key
WHERE d.[date] between getdate()- 10 AND getdate()-9
        AND gg.Game_Group_Description <> 'Bingo'
GROUP BY c.cust_id )


create clustered index S_2 on #temp_shash_B (cust_dup)


SELECT * FROM #temp_shash_A A
LEFT JOIN #temp_shash_B B
ON A.cust_id = B.cust_dup
```

This took just around 5-6 minutes when ran initially. However, it took around 35 minutes when ran today. Can anyone suggest a way for me to optimize this?  Any help appreciated.

PS: I'm working on SQL Server 2008 R2 DB. The query is a dataset query for an SSRS report.

Comment: Have a query plan? Where is the 5-6 minutes spent in the remaining query?

Comment: How many rows are being returned?

Comment: stats and indexes are up-to-date ?

Comment: Have you tried running the DB tuning wizard while you run that report?

Comment: @Zane around 56905 rows are returned

Comment: @Kin -> yes, stats are up to date and index I'm creating in my query

Comment: Can you provide the DDL including indexes for all tables involved and an idea of how many records are in each table.  Also what is the distribution of the 'Prospect', eg are most customers prospects?  Or only 10%.

Comment: To get help on this you really need to include your schema with info on indexes and table structures.

Answer (score 0):

from some research I have found the `<>` or `does not equal` takes longer to run than `=` operations

in [this answer to `SQL Server “<>” operator is very slow compared to “=” on table with a few million rows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7419299/1214743)  the Poster goes into Detail about the `<>` operator and why it takes longer than the `=` operator.

the Poster suggests a `LEFT JOIN` for the OP's Query that would make it so that they shouldn't have to use the `<>` operator.

if you could do something similar to weed out the records that you don't want using a `LEFT JOIN` or something of the sort.  I think the post that I linked to should set you in the right direction.

**P.S.**

it sounds like the same thing happens when you use `NOT IN`